# Install CRM 2011 and SharePoint 2010 on same machine

Tags: installation, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am building a development machine to do some testing.

Can I have CRM 2011 and SharePoint 2010 installed on the same machine? If yes is there a specific order in which they should be installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

having build a CRM development environment on a single VM, I can confirm that installation on the same machine is, indeed, possible. The order where SharePoint is installed first has been recommended, from memory, since Beta. Some gotchas (basically, the idea is to disrupt CRM installation that follows as little as possible):

1. Make sure SharePoint is NOT installed on the default web site and use host headers to separate SharePoint from the default web site.
2. Do install CRM List Component prior to CRM installation.
3. Do NOT install Reporting Services in SharePoint Integration Mode.

The CRM installation after that is a straightforward process as per [Implementation Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9886ab96-3571-420f-83ad-246899482fb4).

Hope it helps.
George

Answer (score 0):

yes i have installed sharepoint 2010 and crm 2011 on same machine. when i installed sharepoint 2010 my crm 2011 site didnt work then i changed the port of crm 2011 from 80 to 81 by using the IIS binding option.